# Arreglo dentro de una consulta SQL en PHP (WHERE...IN)

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Tengo un `array` llamado `$cuentas` de N elementos, dichos elementos quiero pasar uno por uno a una consulta `SQL`, es decir, que de me devuelva un dato por cada elemento dentro del `array` y luego almacenarlo en otro `array`.

He intentado haciendo un `bindParam` dentro de un `foreach` y luego un `execute`, pero tarda mucho ya que esta ejecuntando N veces:

```
foreach($cuentas as $row){
    $stid->bindParam(':cuenta', $row, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stid->execute();
    $resultado = $stid->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}
```

Estoy evitando usar `execute` dentro de un `foreach` por la lentitud de la respuesta.

Lei que podia utilizar `WHERE ... IN` en mi consulta `SQL` pero no logro hacerlo correctamente y no se el porque.

```
$inQuery = str_repeat('?,', count($cuentas) - 1) . '?';
    var_dump($inQuery);

    $stid = $conn->prepare("SELECT SALDO FROM ( SELECT G305.G305S01 AS SALDO 
                                                FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 
                                                WHERE G300.G300CTA IN (:cuenta) AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID 
                                                AND TRUNC(G305.G305FDIA) >= TO_DATE(:fecha,'YYYY-MM-DD')-1 
                                                GROUP BY G300.G300CTA, G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01 
                                                ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC) 
                            WHERE ROWNUM <= 1");
    $stid->bindParam(':fecha', $fechaConsulta, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
    $stid->bindValue(':cuenta', $inQuery, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stid->execute();
    $resultado = $stid->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    // $stid->closeCursor();
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($resultado);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: cual es la estructura del array? es asociativo?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez si, el array es asociativo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu array es de la forma `(1,2,3)`

```
$cuenta = array(1,2,3,4,5); //tu array de valores

$inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($cuenta), '?')); //separamos los valores por , y llenamos el array con ? que son la  cantidad de parametros en la consulta 
 //eso impirmiria algo asi: ?,?,?,?,?

 stid = $conn->prepare("SELECT SALDO FROM ( SELECT G305.G305S01 AS SALDO 
                                            FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 
                                            WHERE G300.G300CTA IN ($inQuery) AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID 
                                            AND TRUNC(G305.G305FDIA) >= TO_DATE(:fecha,'YYYY-MM-DD')-1 
                                            GROUP BY G300.G300CTA, G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01 
                                            ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC) 
                        WHERE ROWNUM <= 1");
```

Ya tienes tu consulta preparada ahora pasamos los valores:

```
 foreach ($cuenta as $key => $value){
    $stid->bindParam($key+1, $value);
  }//estar recorriendo tu array y pasandole los valores a tu bindParam

  $stid->execute();
  $resultado = $stid->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: Que tal? Trate de implementar el siguiente codigo pero me arroja el siguiente error: >Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Comment: tienes una :fecha que debes cambiar por ?

Comment: El error me lo señala donde esta el $inQuery, la fecha es un resultado que trae de un input, eso si funciona

Comment: si pero el inquery es ??? y fecha es :fecha no puedes mesclarlos